# Can a PCB footprint be extracted from a solid model?

Tags: altium, orcad, mechanical

I usually just make a PCB footprint if I need it (Solidworks PCB, Altium, Protel99, OrCAD, etc). I'm an electrical engineer. I've seen very nice 3D solid models for some parts and I wonder if the PCB footprint could be extracted from the 3D model? I know very little to nothing about 3D models. I've seen the word "step" in lots of them and I think Solidworks can open them but besides that I'm clueless.

Could someone enlighten me pls? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't because a footprint never actually matches the exact outline of the component's pins/pads anyways.

Comment: Isn't it easier to look into the datasheet where you have recommended footprint with precise dimensions?

Comment: I use Solidworks' 2D sketching tools (driving dimensions and constraints) to construct the footprint using the datasheet to derive all relations correctly.  Then export as a 2D DXF drawing and import that into PADS or OrCAD etc.  Makes workflow very streamlined.  Forget 3D models for PCB footprints, it's more hassle than just drawing the footprint by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Not very effectively.

A 3D model will, at best, tell you where the part has pins. A footprint needs to specify the size and shape of the pads and soldermask for those pins, which may be significantly different from the shape of the pins themselves. Determining how different it needs to be is often a matter of trial and error to determine what has the best yield in production. (And hand-solderable footprints are another matter entirely.)

If the part uses a more-or-less standard footprint, it's probably feasible to extrapolate a footprint from the model based on footprints for similarly shaped parts. If it's something entirely novel, though, you're best off looking to the manufacturer for recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Software could, but this would be the worst way to do it. You could find the area around the pins and then generate pads around those areas, you may even be able to get Altium to script it for you.

The problem is footprints are also sized to include things like pin tolerances (not all packages are created equal of the same part, the pins are in slightly different positions and this needs to be accounted for) and solder wicking/tensioning (did you know that pins are sized slightly larger than needed in some cases to provide extra solder paste).

For many packages standards have been developed (by [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPC_(electronics)) for one), this means that many libraries already have the footprints for many of the packages available.

It is also increasingly unnecessary to even bother with datasheets and footprints at all.

For example, Altium has a footprint generator that covers (to my estimation 90%) of the parts out there. The latest version of altium also has a manfuacturer search that can many pull footprints *and schematic parts* directly into a design so a designer doesn't even need to bother with foot prints.

Octopart also has footprints available.

[image]

Yes, you'll run into the odd part that doesn't have a footprint available and you'll need to pull it from the datasheet. You'll want to pull the mechanical information of the footprint from the datasheet because the manufacturer has probably tested the tolerances of the footprint with the part which will result in the best outcomes for your PCB layout.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, assuming the model had precise dimensions and wasn't just an artists impression. You could extract the dimensions, use some algorithm to try and figure out where the base is, determine if it's SMD or through hole. Then some set of rules could be used to generate pads, etc.

Though without some sort of standard the models have to follow, it's going to make mistakes.

I'm not really sure what advantage there would be to doing this though?

I think maybe you're looking at it backwards. It's very easy to generate a 3D model from a PCB layout, then your 3D components can be placed onto their foot-prints and you get a complete 3D view of your board.

Going back the other way is more difficult, mostly because it's not something that is standardised.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like Eagle need both a schematic symbol, the mechanical footprint symbol, and then tie them together as a library part so that when you are creating the schematic the footprint for the part shows up on the board for routing.

Having just the footprint doesn't help much, and you are stuck faking the routing and the connections don't show up on the schematic.